# Wring dbf file using dbf_jdbc issue

Tags: java, jdbc, dbf

File can not be renamed after the following code execution:

```
private static final String URL = "jdbc:DBF:/C:\\TEST";
private static final String TABLE = "create table SAMPLE ( "
+ " SM VARCHAR(10), "
+ " PRIM  VARCHAR(10) " + ")"; 

...

Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.setProperty( "charSet", "cp866" );
properties.setProperty( "CODEPAGEID", "66" );

// instantiate it
Class.forName( "com.hxtt.sql.dbf.DBFDriver" ).newInstance();
Connection dbfConn = DriverManager.getConnection( URL, properties );
Statement stmt = dbfConn.createStatement();
stmt.executeUpdate( TABLE );
stmt.close();
PreparedStatement ps = dbfConn.prepareStatement( "INSERT INTO SAMPLE (SM, PRIM) VALUES (?,?);"  );
ps.setString( 1, "test11" );
ps.setString( 2, "test12" );
ps.executeUpdate();
ps.close();
dbfConn.close();
new File( "C:\\TESTarj\\SAMPLE.DBF").renameTo( new File( "C:\\TESTarj\\SAMPLE_renamed.DBF" ) );
```

If you remove `ps.executeUpdate();` file is renamed. The problem appeared only on last **Friday the 13th**. It worked fine before. **dbf_jdbc, Java, tomcat versions have not been changed**. The problem appeared on several boxes at the same time. As a workaround I can use javadbf, but it's not the best choice in our case.

Any ideas what may be a cause of problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 properties.setProperty( "delayedClose", "0" );
```

//delayedClose  Indicates the delayed seconds for close transaction. That option is used to avoid frequent close/open table operations for following sqls. Automatic temporary index is disabled when delayedClose<=60s. You can use 0~120 seconds. Default: 3.

Comment: Thank you very much!!!
I could not understand why it worked before without the property setting.